# Android, screenshot using USB Interface

Tags: android

Is there any way to snap the screen of an Android device connected to a Windows OS in the same manner done by libmibiledevice for iOS ?

Can the screen of a USB connected Android device be snapped using the USB interface ( eg. using WinUSB  APIs )?

Comment: This question is off-topic and not a programming question!

Comment: I want to do that programatically using C++

Comment: You should mention required details in question itself, just to avoid comments and questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the way to go:**

- Android Debug Bridge code with Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition
  project @ https://github.com/t-mat/my_adb.git
- Android Screen Monitor @
  https://code.google.com/p/android-screen-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

you could leverage adb for this:

```
 adb shell screencap /sdcard/pic.png ; adb pull /sdcard/pic.png
```

Comment: I need to do that programatically ( using WinUSB ), and, while having an AOA2 session open...

Answer (score 0):

use android studio ( there is "screen capture" function) 
An alternative is to use  teamviewer for android

Comment: I need to have this done programatically, hence, using C++ code